# Python rs232 conection Protek 506

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

Hi I have a big problem to do a connection with Protek (https://docs.google.com/a/fisica.ugto.mx/gview?url=http://www.radiomanual.info/schemi/ACC_instrument/Protek_506-505-504_user.pdf&chrome=true)

I have this code:

```
import time
import serial


ser = serial.Serial(
port='COM3',
baudrate=9600,
parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS

)

ser.isOpen()

print 'Ingresa el comando.\r\nInserta "exit" para salir de la aplicación.'

input=1
while 1 :
# entrada teclado
input = raw_input(" ")
if input == 'exit':
    ser.close()
    exit()
else:
    # Envía caracter al dispositivo
    ser.write(input + '\r')
    out = ''

    #tiempo para recibir respuesta
            time.sleep(10)
    while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
        out += ser.read(1)

    if out != '':
        print ">>" + out
```

I tried to enter the next string "DC 3 999 V" and the device return the voltage, but doesn't return anything.

Comment: Hopw it will help you..[http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/serial%20rs232%20connections%20python]

Answer (score 0):

Reading the datasheet, the serial port configuration **needs to be `1200,N,7,2`**.

Your current code is configured for `9600,N,8,2`.

Answer (score 0):

My Protek worked correctly only after i changed port configuration to `1200,E,7,1` .